# XAMPP-python script execution

Tags: php, python, apache, xampp

i am trying to execute a python script in my XAMPP server but i get a blank page each time i call the script. When i try to execute it in the adress localhost/cgi-bin/script.py it works fine but when i try to execute it in htdocs it comes in blank. In my htdocs directory i have 2 files:

**html file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<form name="input" action="http://localhost/insert.PHP"    method="post">
User: <input type="text" name="user" value="Obama"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="pass">


<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

**insert.php file which brings .py file to execute:**

```
<?php

$Nome = $_POST['user'];
$Password = $_POST['pass'];

echo ini_get("disable_functions");



$python = exec('C:\xampp\cgi-bin\script.py');
echo $python;

?>
```

**finally .py file (script.py) in cgi-bin directory:**

```
#!C:\Python27\python.exe

import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-Type: text/html"
print
print """
    <TITLE>CGI script</TITLE>
    <H1> just fine !</H1>
"""
print " <p>I am a script in python! </p>"
```

So i type User and password, it redirects to insert.php and i get a blank page. Thanks!

Comment: Read the documentation of PHP exec. http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php It does *not* return the full output of the command executed. And why do you run the python script through PHP in the first place? Why not execute it directly?

Comment: thanks, the problem was really calling from php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have safe mode enabled which prevents execution outside of safe mode directory. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php description.

You can also try using system() function instead.

I also think that it is not a great idea to call python script from php. :)

EDIT:
If you are on development environment, I would suggest you try to following:

1) copy script.py to the directory where your .php file is.

2) change .php exec line to system('python script.py');

3) if that works, try to call .py in cgi-bin directory. if cgi-bin is one level up from your htdocs directory, you can try system('python ..\cgi-bin\script.py');

I can't try it on my machine, since I run Mac.

4) I looked at safe mode description, it seems it was removed in PHP 5.4.0. So if your version of PHP is higher than that, it should not apply to you.

5) I would suggest also trying forward slashes in path: system('python ../cgi-bin/script.py');

Good luck. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Yerke. How do you suggest i call my script ?  I am new at this stuff :s

Comment: I solved when i changed <form name="input" action="http://localhost/insert.PHP"    method="post"> to <form name="input" action="http://localhost/cgi-bin/script.py" method="post">. I seems that your guess was right, i will never try again to call from a php file.